# Youtube API or Link ... retrieving unlisted videos?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm having trouble grabbing the last 4 upload "unlisted" videos from my youtube account. I can do it with public but it won't work with unlist. Is there a gdata api i can use?

this is what I use for public and then parse the results.
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UserName/uploads?orderby=updated&max-results=4

Comment: You will probably need to Authorize request: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Authentication.  Which language do you will use ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to authenticate your request

see : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc

shell example :

```
# getting auth token
TOKEN=$(curl --silent 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin' --data-urlencode Email=YOUR_EMAIL --data-urlencode Passwd='YOUR_PASSWORD' -d accountType=GOOGLE -d source=SO -d service=youtube | grep Auth)

# call api with Authorization
curl --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin $AUTH" "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UserName/uploads?orderby=updated&max-results=50"
```

for PHP, take a look at this page :
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible due to the intended privacy of unlisted videos.

From the developer guide: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc

> "Unlisted videos are not included in search results or displayed in
>   any other way, and a user can only reach an unlisted video by entering
>   or linking directly to the video's watch page URL."

Comment: can I just login to my account and grab the links that way?

Comment: You can retrieve unlisted videos using just an API key if you add them to a playlist. If you do not add them to a playlist they will not be accessible using the API key and you will need to go the OAuth route. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56652852/2344394

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky. Unlisted video is the  one that 
a) does not have  
b) has

However, the problem is that YT upload API does not return  for any video entry, just only  or none. You probably have to make another API call to pull up the video's yt:accessControl ?

Comment: I figured it out :) You have to use uploads API v=2 in order to get yt:accessControl tag.