# How to get all videos from my own YouTube channel via YouTube Data API v3

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get the ID and title for all videos from my own YouTube channel. Some of videos are *unlisted*, but I want to get them too. I use this version of the client library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev222-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```

According to the documentation I use this Java code:

```
YouTube.Search.List request = youtubeService.search()
            .list("id,snippet");
SearchListResponse response = request.setChannelId(channelId)
            .setForMine(true)
            .setMaxResults(50L)
            .setType("video")
            .execute();
```

But got this exception:

```
400 Bad Request
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=channelId&forMine=true&maxResults=50&part=id,snippet&type=video
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.search",
    "location" : "parameters.",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set either the <code>forContentOwner</code> or <code>forMine</code> parameters to <code>true</code>. You must also set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters.",
    "reason" : "invalidSearchFilter"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set either the <code>forContentOwner</code> or <code>forMine</code> parameters to <code>true</code>. You must also set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters."
}
```

Moreover I got the same error using interactive tool on this page:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true`.

If I remove `.setForMine(true)` it works fine, but doesn't give me *unlisted* videos (gives me only public videos).

Are there any possibilities to get the ID and title of all videos (*unlisted* included) from my own channel via the API?

Comment: There's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454378/youtube-api-get-unlisted-videos from five years ago, not sure if it will still works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: indeed, there is an API that will provide *all* video metadata of your channel, including the metadata of *unlisted* videos.

For the longer answer, just bear with me for a while:

First thing, do note that a given video has a privacy status of the following kinds:

> [**`status.privacyStatus`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus) (string)
> The video's privacy status.
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - private
> - public
> - unlisted

For to obtain the IDs of all videos uploaded by your channel, irrespective of their privacy status, you'll have to invoke the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint queried with the parameter [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) set to the ID of your channel's uploads playlist, *while issuing an OAuth authorized request* (that is: passing to the API a valid access token; using only an API key will make the endpoint return only public videos):

```java
List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"); // or ".../auth/youtube"

Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "myuploads");

youtube = new YouTube.Builder(
    Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
    .setApplicationName("myuploads")
    .build();
```

```
List<String> videoIdList = new ArrayList<String>();

YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemRequest =
    youtube.playlistItems().list("contentDetails");
playlistItemRequest.setFields("nextPageToken,items/contentDetails/videoId");
playlistItemRequest.setMaxResults(50);
playlistItemRequest.setPlaylistId(uploadsPlaylistId);

String nextToken = "";
do {
    playlistItemRequest.setPageToken(nextToken);
    PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemResult = playlistItemRequest.execute();

    for (PlaylistItem playlistItem: playlistItemResult.getItems())
        videoIdList.add(playlistItem.getContentDetails().getVideoId());

    nextToken = playlistItemResult.getNextPageToken();
} while (nextToken != null);
```

Now, the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint will provide you all the metadata of the videos of which IDs are collected by `videoIdList`.

```
List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<Video>();
while (videoIdList.size() > 0) {
    int endIndex = videoIdList.size() < 50 ? videoIdList.size() : 50;
    List<String> subList = videoIdList.subList(0, endIndex);

    YouTube.Videos.List videosRequest =
        youtube.videos().list("id,contentDetails,status,snippet, statistics");
    videosRequest.setId(String.join(",", subList));
    VideoListResponse videosResponse = videoRequest.execute();

    videoList.AddAll(videosResponse.getItems());

    subList.clear();
}
```

Note that, if `videoIdList` is of size `N` at the beginning of the loop above -- since the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) of `Videos.list` endpoint can be specified as a comma-separated list of video IDs --, the loop code reduces the number of calls to `Videos.list` endpoint from `N` to `Math.floor(N / 50) + (N % 50 ? 1 : 0)` by appropriately using the feature of `id` just mentioned.

The uploads playlist ID -- `uploadsPlaylistId` -- may very easily be obtained by invoking the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint queried with the parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) set to your channel's ID, or, otherwise, queried with the parameter [`mine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#mine) set to `true`:

```
YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest =
    youtube.channels().list("contentDetails");
channelRequest.setMine(true);
channelRequest.setFields("items/contentDetails/relatedPlaylists/uploads");
ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute();
```

Note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) parameter for to get from the API only the info that's needed.

The uploads playlist ID is then to be found within the endpoint's JSON response as value of the property:

[`items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).

Translated to Java, this property path would become the following chain of getters, ending with [`getUploads`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/ChannelContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.html#getUploads--):

`channelResult.getItems().get(0).getContentDetails().getRelatedPlaylists().getUploads()`.

Note that for a given channel, you need to obtain the uploads playlist ID only once, then use it as many times as you wish. Usually, a channel ID and its corresponding uploads playlist ID are related by `s/^UC([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{22})$/UU\1/`.

For an almost complete implementation of the API calls I described above (excluding the loop that fills up the list `videoList`), I'll recommend to make use of the following sample program from Google: [`MyUploads.java`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/MyUploads.java). The loop that constructs the list `videoList` is similar to the one found in [`GeolocationSearch.java`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/GeolocationSearch.java). The implementation of method `Auth.authorize` is to be found in [`Auth.java`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the brilliant answer. please, add `nextPageToken` into `setFields` for playlistItems request